# Erro ao executar o inner join no python

Tags: python, pandas, join, inner

Estou fazendo um cruzamento de duas planilhas em .xslx usando o seguinte código:

```
import pandas as pd


d3 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\t718787\Desktop\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\diretoriox\d3.txt', encoding='latin1', sep=';', names =['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14'])

d3.to_excel(r'C:\Users\t718787\Desktop\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\diretoriox\d3.xlsx',header=False, index = False )

d3 = d3.rename(columns = {'6' : 'Compromisso'})
d3 = d3.rename(columns = {'8' : 'Remessa'})



i = 0

arqG6 = open(r'C:\Users\t718787\Desktop\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\diretoriox\d5.txt')
colunas = ['compromisso', 'remessa']
dados = []


    
for line in arqG6:
    column = line


    if(i == 1):
        
        compromisso = column[5:16]
        
        remessa = column[28:60]
        
        dados.append([compromisso, remessa])
        
        #print('{} , {} '.format(compromisso, remessa))
            
        i = 0

    if(column[5:16] == 'COMPROMISSO'):
        i = 1
    

df = pd.DataFrame(dados, columns=colunas)


arqG6.close()
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\t718787\Desktop\Anaconda3 (64-bit)\diretoriox\d5.xlsx', index = False) 


join_cond = (d3['Compromisso'] == df['compromisso']) & (d3['Remessa'] == df['remessa'])


df1 = pd.concat((d3[join_cond], df[join_cond][['teste']]), axis=1)
```

porém nessa parte

```
join_cond = (d3['Compromisso'] == df['compromisso']) & (d3['Remessa'] == df['remessa'])


df1 = pd.concat((d3[join_cond], df[join_cond][['teste']]), axis=1)
```

apresenta o seguinte erro

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

procurei alguns post sobre, mas nada que tenha me ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

```
df1 = pd.merge(df3[['Compromisso','Remessa']], df[['compromisso','remessa']],
    left_on=['Compromisso','Remessa'], right_on=['Compromisso','Remessa'], how='inner'))
```

Comment: Se possível, não poste somente o códio. Complemente a resposta com uma explicação sobre como e porque esse código funciona.

Comment: testei esse trecho de código e da erro de syntax, poderia explicar melhor, como funcionaria no código esse trecho ?